# How to run eslint so that I can attach a debugger?

Tags: javascript, eslint, javascript-debugger

I am trying to debug a `eslint` rule through `console.log` but it's not the most efficient way to debug. I am running `eslint` through command line.

How can I run `eslint` so that I can attach a debugger (either VSCode debugger or Chrome debugger) to it? I see I can pass a debug url to VSCode, but I don't know how to get the url.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37014329/7424948) which points to http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/development, but I get a page not found and I've tried looking for debug/debugger/development/inspector, but didn't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running `eslint` is running a NodeJS script so you can run [node with `--inspect` switch](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/).

### 1. Get the debug url

1. Find the location of `eslint` script (likely `node_modules/.bin/eslint`)
2. Run node in inspect mode : `node --inspect-brk {eslint_path} {file_path}`

For example : `node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/eslint .`

3. You'll see a line `Debugger listening on {url}`, this is your debug url.

### 2. Attach the debugging client.

### With Chrome

1. Go to Chrome, type `chrome://inspect` in the url bar
2. If "Discover network targets" is checked, you should be able to see `node_modules/.bin/eslint ...` under "Remote targets"[image]
3. Likely a new Chrome window named "DevTools" with the source code in debug mode should have popped up. If not, open the developer tools, and click on the Node logo and it should open the window.[image]
4. The execution is stopped on the first instruction. You can now use Chrome debugger.

### With VSCode

**Set up (only needs to be done once)**

1. Click on "Run and Debug" on the left
2. This step depends if you already configured your `launch.js` file.

   1. If you see a green triangle (it means you have configured it), click "Attach" next to the green triangle -> Add Configuration
   2. If you see a lot of text with three blue buttons (it's not configured yet), select "Show all automatic debug configurations" -> Add Configuration
3. Choose "Node.js: Attach".
4. Name your configuration

**Attach debugger**

Go to "Run and Debug" and click on the green triangle next to your configuration name.

##### Note

We use `--inspect-brk` in order to stop the execution right away, otherwise the execution will likely be done by the time you attach your debugging client. If you already added a `debugger` instruction in your code, then you can run `--inspect` and it will stop at the first `debugger` instruction.